# Current and voltage driven rectifiers

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier

While going through resonant DC-DC converters, I came across two types of generally used rectifiers.
[image]

The above image is current driven rectifier and it makes sense why one wants to drive it with current sources, because using voltage sources would cause current spikes when the diodes start conducting (i.e., when the input voltage rises above the output voltage).

Now here comes my question.

What would happen if a voltage driven rectifier, shown below is driven by a current source?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to simulate it? If not, please do to build your own understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you must drive your choke input rectifier with a current source then be careful about peak voltages across the choke and the fast rectifier diodes .

Answer (score 0):

Adding only a head capacitor will reduce peak voltage Then, energy would be transfered to other capacitor through inductor, without losses ...